# Store Specific string from Html Page into PHP variable

Tags: php, javascript, helper

i have complete html page, i need to store a specific string value in php variable.

specific value i can only select by css selector. but i have to store it in php variable.

however i can do complete this work in javascript with some easy code but i have to do this by php can somebody advice.

javascript solution.

`<script>
    <script>  var xa = document.querySelector("span.posted_in a").text;
    document.write(xa);
    </script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is running on the server. PHP generates the page code (HTML) that the client sees. Once the page is generated and the code is received, PHP ends. Everything, there is no more PHP. The client in the browser sees what the server spits out to him. To send data from the browser back to the server, you must re-query the server.

AJAX will help you, maybe.

Comment: I understand but i have checked many DOM ajax as on other sites. also i have experience is the same code is working on other server but slow, so i 'm considering is issue in my server code was fine. thanks for help